# Lag when exporting functionality into a block in Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm new to scratch.

I have this code within a sprite, which works as expected without noticeable lags:

[image]

But, when I "export" the flickering into the 'flicker' block, it has a very nasty lag:

[image]

I created a special sprite in order to easily "feel" the lag, with this code:

[image]

This ball smoothly moves, until (every 5 seconds) there is the flickering effect and it stops for 1 second or so.

Can anyone give me a clue why it happens, and how to prevent it?

The project page is [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/635172361).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by pointing out that the problem does not occur when I launch [your project](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/635172361).
I tried it in 5 different web browsers on 3 different devices with 2 different operating systems, and every time, the ball just kept moving.

However, I *can* make such an issue happen by enabling 'Run without screen refresh' in the 'flicker' block, as follows:

- Right-click on the red 'define flicker' block.
- From the context menu, select 'Edit'.
- In the 'make a block' dialog, turn on checkbox 'Run without screen refresh', then click OK.

I suspect 'Run without screen refresh' claims all processing power, effectively blocking any other (concurrent) scripts.

My guess is, you already fixed the problem yourself by turning off 'Run without screen refresh'.

In general, 'Run without screen refresh' is a great way to reduce lag in scripts where speed is essential. But **never** use it in a script with 'wait' or 'forever' blocks, or it will *cause* lag.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. :)